# How to identify parent of child events?

Tags: standard-objects, calendar

**Question**

Given a child event, how can I find it's parent?

**Background**

We're working on a terminated user tool.  One component of that is transferring future events for that user to their replacement.  For child events (events a user was added as an invitee for) we'd like to remove them as an invitee and add their replacement as an invitee.

If an invitee is added to an event a new event is created with invitee as the owner and the isChild flag is set to true.  However, based on the [Event docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_event.htm) there there isn't a parentId field I can find that links the child event to the parent.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its a bit confusing, but I think the [EventRelation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm) is the key. The child Event will have an EventRelation record with the EventId equal to the Parent Event and the RelationId for each User.

[image: Task and Event Objects] ([Source](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_activities.htm))

Comment: I don't believe EventRelation can help here. For a meeting (parent) with multiple attendees you will have multiple EventRelation objects with eventId=parentId and relationId=userId (attendee). There wont be any EventRelation objects linking to any child events. Any other ideas?