# Find Parent Event of Child Event

Tags: event

**Problem Statement**

Show a list of events on visualforce page, and give ability to respond as accept/reject/maybe.

**Scenario:**

- 3 users are participating in an event.
- Event is created by a user named "Ab Jindal" and he invites two other sfdc users i.e. "Ab Dev" and "Sm Dev"
- Here is event data with parent event and eventrelations created for owner "Ab Jindal"
  [image: Event table query]
- EventRelation table data for this event:
  [image: EventRelation table data]

From above screenshots, its clear that one needs Parent Event Id to update any EventRelation. Even if we try to hack and create a new EventRelation record via invited user i.e. "Ab Dev" or "Sm Dev", it will fail. Here is sample failure code

```
EventRelation er = new EventRelation(
                           RelationId = UserInfo.getUserId()  ,  
                           EventId = '00U2000000VcrubEAB',
                           Status = 'Declined'
                     );

insert er;
```

Here is the error which comes on executing above code:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: INVALID_OPERATION, You cannot create an Event Relation with a
>   child event.: [EventId]

So, I wanted to know either of following two questions:

- How we can get parent event id from a child event ?
- Or, how to update child event with accept/decline/maybe info ?

**Similar Questions**

On researching found [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10091/how-to-identify-parent-of-child-events/10093#10093) which is somewhat close to my challenge, but is not having correct resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Event Relation records to be inserted always with status as "New" but, later it can be updated to "Accepted" or "Declined" .

**Insert :**

```
EventRelation er = new EventRelation(
                           RelationId = UserInfo.getUserId()  ,  
                           EventId = '00U2000000VcrubEAB',
                           Status = 'New'
                     );

insert er;
```

**Update** :

Get event id  from event object.
Then query to Event Relation and get the id(event relation record id) ;

```
EventRelation er = new EventRelation(
                           Id = "EventRelation rec id",  
                           Status = 'Declined'
                     );

update er;
```

Answer (score -1):

To decline the status, you will have to perform update not insert.
Eventid & Relationid is not required to accept or reject the event.

Comment: As described in the question, I am unable to do update, as ParentId is not available on child event. So without getting a correct parentid, its not possible.