# Mock child events in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, event

I need to create a child event isChild=true with apex. I need it in my test class. any suggestion.

```
    Event ev1=new Event 
    (OwnerId=u.Id, Subject= 'Appel',
    WhoId =  whoCon.Id,
    StartDateTime = Datetime.now(),
    EndDateTime= Datetime.now()+1);
    insert ev1;

    EventRelation er = new EventRelation();
    er.RelationId= u1.Id;
    insert er;  
    er.EventId = ev1.Id;
    update er;

    System.debug('#### EVENT 1 ischild ' + ev1.isChild);
```

I still got ischild = false.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my understanding is you don't need to explicitly create a child event..

If an invitee is added to an event a new event is created with invitee as the owner and the isChild flag is set to true.

Refer this previous discussion : [How to identify parent of child events?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10091/how-to-identify-parent-of-child-events)

So after you create your actual Event and the EventRelation, there should be a child event created automatically.

you can query that back and use it in your test class

```
List<Event> childEvents = [select id,ischild from event where subject = 'Appel' and isChild = true];
```

Comment: Inserting an EventRelation with IsInvitee set doesn't create an Event with IsChild set in my testing: https://gist.github.com/cwarden/c86511a7a6d05b19a5c6d45aa0a66ad1
Am I missing something?

Comment: @xn. Apparently, the test method needs to be marked with SeeAllData=true or child events are not created/queryable. Weird and and apparently undocumented, but it seems to be the case.