# Can't create EventRelation for Event in Test Class

Tags: event

I'm working on a trigger to retrieve event attendees from the EventRelation object. In my test class I am creating an event and then an EventRelation as follows:

```
Event event = new Event( Subject = 'Test Event', StartDateTime=start, EndDateTime=finish);       
insert event;

EventRelation er = new EventRelation(EventId = event.Id, RelationId = mycontact.Id);

insert er;

event.Subject = 'Updated Event';

update event;
```

However, if I try to query this back no record gets returned.

```
List<EventRelation> evr = [Select Id, RelationId From EventRelation Where EventId =: event.Id];
```

I've tried in my Trigger and test class to query this back but to no avail. What could be the problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to make query in the same test method or in the same transaction?

Comment: I answered a similar question a while ago - this might help you : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83341/mock-child-events-in-test-class

Comment: It doesn't work in both trigger and test class. Ideally my trigger will be able to query an event, pull back all attendees and their statuses but so far I can't query back the event's attendees.

Comment: and the debug log shows no errors?

Comment: No there are no errors in the logs - just no rows returned for the query.

Comment: did you ever get this figured out? I'm running into a similar issue.